# Decompose Point-Spread Function into Seidel Aberration/Zernike Polynomials

Tags: fitting, image

I have measured the point spread function (PSF of a microscope) and I want to quantify it. For that purpose I want to fit my PSF data to the primary Seidel optical aberrations (or Zernike Polynomials, if it makes it easier). Something [similar](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PointSpreadAndModulationTransferFunctionsForSeidelAberration/) already exists on the Mathematica Demonstration center, but it is the opposite of what I want.

The PSF data is stored in TIFF files, and consists of images of sub-resolution dots taken at various focal distances.

Comment: I propose you read the gray level values from your TIFF files and then use `NonlinearModelFit` with a few of the the Zernicke Polynomials as bases.  (It would be much better if you had direct numerical PSF readings rather than have to extract them from an image file in TIFF.)

Comment: What do you mean with "to have direct numerical PSF readings"

Comment: @phildelio:  I mean a file containing real values at spatail positions, e.g., {{0.024, 0.368, 0.119, ...}, ...}.

Comment: The real values at spatial positions can be only integers, since light intensity is quantized in photons.

Comment: Point-spread functions are defined as continuous valued (never discrete valued for real systems).  For instance, one of the most common PSFs is the *Sinc* function (the PSF of a unit aperture in one dimension).  Even though each individual capture of photons will be discrete, the PSF is fully continuous.  If you average over an extremely large (infinite) number of samples, each grid point yields a continuous real value.  You can read about this in pretty much any optics textbook, including the one I wrote (see Amazon.com) or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function.

Comment: Mr. Stork, congratulations on your book. Now, about PSFs. They are defined in wave optics, which assumes light intensity can have any arbitrary number. However, in real life energy is quantized (in photons), therefore this condition is no longer valid. Infinite number of samples are experimentally unobtainable. If you take the average of several measurements, then of course the result will be a real valued data set, since you are dividing two integers (photon/number of measurements). I don't see, however, why can't you fit a real valued function to a integer data (e.g. fitting a histogram).

Comment: You cannot define the PSF as integer-valued because 1) The PSF describes the continuous *probability* of finding a photon.  2) The PSF's range--$(x,y)$ or $(r, \theta)$--on the sensor plane is continuous. Consider an optical system has axial symmetry so the PSF must be radial, i.e., $PSF = a(r) b(\theta)$.  But both the PSF and $\theta$ are continuous. 3) The Zernike polynomials are all *continuous* and can be derived from the (continuous) PSF. 5), 6), ... Try to find any book/paper with an actual or solved PSF (Airy disk, Sinc, etc.) as integer-valued.  (I bet you're in CS--not EE or optics.)

Comment: OK. stop for a moment and read what I am saying. I agree that the PSF is defined as a real-valued function. What I am saying is that if you measure the intensity with sufficient sensitivity, you would see only integer values. The reason is that light energy is quantized and an individual quantum is call a photon. So far, so good. Now, my question is why is it a problem to fit a real valued function to an integer data?

Comment: Yes, you can fit a continuous function through integer data.

Comment: So, I guess the whole discussion was pointless in the end.

Comment: Not pointless so long as you realize the error in your statement "about PSFs. They are defined in wave optics, which assumes light intensity can have any arbitrary number. However, in real life energy is quantized (in photons), therefore this condition is no longer valid."  PSFs do NOT assume light intensity can have an arbitrary number.  Instead, PSFs describe the *probability* of a given number of photons, which *can* be an arbitrary real number.  I urge you to read a basic optics text... mine or any other.  [Over and out.]